# Express $\cos 4\theta$ in terms of $\cos\theta$ using De Moivre’s Theorem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[image]
I don’t understand the working

Comment: They have equated the real parts

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 2):

After using De Moivre's Theorem, they equal imaginary and real parts (because the equality only holds iff the real and imaginary parts on both parts of the equation of $\cos (4\theta) +  i \sin (4 \theta)$ are the same) then  $$ Re(\cos (4\theta) +i\sin (4\theta)) = \cos (4\theta) = Re(c^4-6c^2s^2 +s^4+ i(4c^3s-4cs^3) = c^4-6c^2s^2 +s^4$$
 then using $\sin (x)^2 = 1 - \cos (x) ^2$ they replace the sinus everywhere and just simplify things.